# Coded UI Test data driven in UIMap.cs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I have a lot of codeduitest. There are common test step in each test method. For example; this.UImap.navigatetourl(); I have moved it in UIMap.cs. Because I have changed code for navigatetourl().I want to run the same test method for different urls. I can use data driven test in CodedUITest but I want to use data driven test in UIMap.cs. What can I do?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Take your UIMap.NavigateToUrl() method and add a parameter to it for the URL you want to go to. Use that value to set the appropriate *Params property in your UIMap before actually doing the the navigation. (I'm assuming you recorded a navigation action of some kind?)

In your CodedUI test, take the relevant value from your data source and pass it through to the UIMap.NavigateTo() method as the URL parameter value.